# Get DOM element without using id or class

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a really specific use case, I need to get a dom element, it's an anchor tag, but it doesn't have a class or id, the only attributes it has is "rel", "ios-src" and it has a `<img />` child which also doesn't have an id or a class. I cannot modify the code.

How could I query the element in pure javascript?

This is how the anchor tag looks:

```
<a rel="ar" href="https://example.com/cool-model.usdz#applePayButtonType=pay....etc">  <img src="poster.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: You can share the anchor tag as well.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You should explain it better , but you can Dom element by tag name .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("a[rel='ar']"))
```

```html
<a rel="ar" href="https://example.com/cool-model.usdz#applePayButtonType=pay....etc"> <img src="poster.jpg"></a>
```